# How to access outer outer class(not outer class) property?

Tags: java, syntax, inner-classes, outer-classes

For example,if A has inner class B,B has inner class C,all have a property "name",I know C can access name in B by B.this.name,but how to access name in A from C?

```
public class A{
    String name="A";
    public class B{
        String name="B";
        public class C{
            String name="C";
            public C(){
                //how to print name in A?
                //System.out.println(B.A.name);
                //System.out.println(B.A.this.name);
                //System.out.println(B.this.A.name);
                //System.out.println(B.this.A.this.name);
            }
        }
        C c=new C();
    }
    B b=new B();
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new A();
    }
}
```

I tried so many syntax but they cannot compile,also when search java outer class,I found most of them are about outer class only, not outer outer class.

Comment: Why you are creating this much complexity any specific reason?

Comment: Pass "A" to "B" constructor and Pass "B" to  "C" constructor if you really require these nested classes

Comment: @DiSaSteR, there's no inheritance here. `super()` will call `Object` class' constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `A.this.name` to access the outer most class. Or any other class.

Answer (score 1):

Using `System.out.println(A.this.name);`